# Get last 6 months sales with 0 values & status = Paid

Tags: mysql

how can i return total sales per month (last 6 months) with Paid status only.

Everything is fine if i take out **WHERE sg.status_payment = 'Paid'** from Sql Query but both records will be displayed (Paid/Unpaid).

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(last_6_months.date, '%b %y') AS year_and_month, IFNULL(SUM(sg.total_amt), 0) as TotalSales
FROM (
SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 5 month) date FROM dual UNION
SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 4 month) date FROM dual UNION
SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 3 month) date FROM dual UNION
SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 2 month) date FROM dual UNION
SELECT (now() + interval 1 day - interval 1 month) date FROM dual UNION
SELECT now() month FROM dual
)
last_6_months Left JOIN sales_general sg
ON DATE_FORMAT(sg.posting_date, '%b %y') = DATE_FORMAT(last_6_months.date, '%b %y')
WHERE sg.status_payment = 'Paid' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(last_6_months.date, '%b %y');
```

Expected Result:

| Month | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Feb 23 | 0.00 |
| Mar 23 | 104.00 |
| Apr 23 | 0.00 |
| May 23 | 0.00 |
| Jun 23 | 672.00 |
| Jul 23 | 194.00 |

Comment: *how can i return total sales .. with Paid status only* `SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Paid' THEN sale ELSE 0 END)`?